# How to send http request from different IPs in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I need to send http request from different IPs in jmeter. As of the Number of Threads, for each thread the request has to be made from different IPs. How can I do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `Source address` input under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) sampler where you can specify the source IP address for the request.

[image: Source address]

If you need to use multiple ones, you can put a JMeter Variable there and populate its value via i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Remember that the IP address must be either "real" IP address associated with the physical network card or a ["virtual IP address"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_IP_address), you cannot put a random arbitrary IP addres there.

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) guide for more detailed description, configuration instructions and demo.

Comment: In jmeter does this possible to open websocket connections from different IP addresses configured on same machine?